The number of zeros in the significant digits of the binary representation of the decimal number value is determined?
The program prints the text "value: " on standard output.
The user enters a positive integer in the decimal system for value.
Output a line break.
The number of zeros in the significant digits of the binary representation of the decimal number value is determined.
Depending on the number of zeros in the significant digits, one of the following texts is output on the standard output. In the following texts, the placeholder  is replaced with the selected value and the placeholder  with the number of zeros in the significant digits.
the significant digits of the binary representation of the decimal number value contain exactly one zero: "The number  contains 1 zero in the significant digits of the binary representation!"
the significant digits of the binary representation of the decimal number value contain no or more than one zero: "The number  contains  zeros in the significant digits of the binary representation!"
After output, the program exits successfully with the return value EXIT_SUCCESS.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>  // Header für SCNu32 und PRIu32
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
uint32_t value;
int count_zeros = 0;

printf("value: ");
scanf("%" SCNu32, &value);
printf("\n");
       // Zählen der Nullen in den signifikanten Stellen der Binärrepräsentation
    while (value % 2 == 0) {
        count_zeros++;
        value >>= 1;
    }
    // Ausgabe der entsprechenden Nachricht basierend auf der Anzahl der Nullen
if (count_zeros == 1) {
    printf("The number %" PRIu32 " contains 1 zero in the significant digits of the binary   representation!\n", value);
} else {
    printf("The number %" PRIu32 " contains %d zeros in the significant digits of the binary representation!\n", value, count_zeros);
}
return EXIT_SUCCESS;

}
